# Best way to find difference between two values in a cyclic system?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Take for example time: if we have the starting hour and ending hour, what's the best way to find the number of hours between them?

If we take a 12-hour clock, we'd get the following results

- from 1 to 5 = 4
- from 11 to 1 = 2

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: If your inputs are always integers, you're going to be hard-pressed to beat the *do a lookup in a precomputed array* method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming input already in range 1-12, you might do

```
return b - a + (b < a) * 12;
```

[benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/4JatmpLmWM8ZFipo7wCFghOmAQA) showing a 2 times performance gain over cigien's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64684539/8372853).

Comment: It's still going to be hard to answer the "most efficient" way part of the question ;) Also, you should mention what other solution your benchmark is comparing as well.

Comment: @cigien is compared with your solution `((b + 12) - a) % 12` and his solution is 1.9 times faster, but I don't know if it is very reliable to use `const_expr` which solves at compile time, the test should be done at runtime.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes, I know that, but the answer should have that information in there. And the `constexpr` doesn't make a difference here, because the benchmark calls the function with volatile arguments, so all calls happen at run time anyway.

Comment: @cigien oops, I didn't pay atention to that `volatile`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming a 12 hour clock, the number of hours from `a` to `b` can be calculated as:

```
difference = ((b + 12) - a) % 12;
```

This also assumes that `a` and `b` are both in the range `[1, 12]`. In case they are not, you can do:

```
a %= 12;
b %= 12;
```

before doing the difference calculation.

Comment: close but not perfect: https://godbolt.org/z/ETvc3r question is what are the exact requirements (still failure is not what is expected).

Comment: @MarekR This is getting the "forward" difference, not the minimum difference. 1 to 5 is 4, but 5 to 1 is 8.

Comment: @MarekR I don't think that's what the OP means. They want the number of hours *from* the first value *to* the second. Otherwise the OP's second expected output would have been 10 instead of 2.

Comment: It does the right thing, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way, perhaps, involving some trickery

Comment: @Hrisip Oh, when you say "efficient" do you mean in terms of performance? I wouldn't worry about that at all. Just write the code that's easiest to understand, and let the compile handle the rest :)

Comment: @cigien, no-no, I know what I want. And I want to know the most performant way to do that. Even if it's architecture-specific.

Comment: @Hrisip Ok, then my answer is the most efficient way to do it :) I don't have any evidence for this of course (apart from the fact that compilers are *very* good at optimizing pieces of code like this), but my point is that I don't think you have any evidence that this could be improved either ;) May I also ask, *why* do you want this? Have you discovered this to be a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: @cigien, just want to know if there's such a way. Good know things like that. Gives a deeper understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Hrisip Absolutely. I apologize if I sounded like I was suggesting that you not learn something, I'm definitely not doing that. It's just that performance is a *very* complicated topic, and depends upon a lot of factors. It's not clear to me your comfort level with that material. e.g. are you comfortable reading assembly?

Comment: @cigien, absolutely comfortable. And I'm familiar with the complexity of the topic, but I doubt there's any such complexity for such a task.

Comment: @cigien: *"Ok, then my answer is the most efficient way to do it :)"* I beat you [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/4JatmpLmWM8ZFipo7wCFghOmAQA) ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Hey, very nice :) You should add an answer.

Comment: @Jarod42, yes! That's precisely what I was thinking of. Use that technique myself to avoid branching.

Comment: @Hrisip Ok, then I suggest adding the [performance] tag to the question, and being a little more explicit about what you mean by "efficient".

Comment: @Hrisip There's no branching in my solution either, it's the `%` that's expensive.

Comment: @Hrisip I see that you've accepted Jarod42's answer. But that goes back to the issue of,  that solution is only faster than mine. How do you know there isn't an even faster solution out there?

Comment: @cigien, I meant for different problems. I'm sorry for not being clear on so many things :)   As for "an even faster solution" -- I can't imagine a better solution. It's one of those "I know it when I see it"

Comment: @Hrisip You have nothing to apologize for :) We were both not fully understanding each other, but we worked through it :) By the way, here's a piece of advice, if you ask a performance question on SO in the future (and I hope you do), avoid statements like "I can't imagine a better solution", and "I'll know it when I see it". That's going to upset some users :p